# Resetting SQS MessageRetentionPeriod property didn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

I've got an very simple AWS CloudFormation Template which just to create a SQS resource, the main part looks like this:

```
 "Resources" : {
      "Queue" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        "Properties" : {
          "QueueName" : "QueueA"
        }
      }
    }
```

I deployed this (by creating a new stack), well, as the [official document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-sqs-queue-msgretentionperiod) suggests, the default retention period is 4 days, I checked, it was set to 4 days, so far so good.

Then I made a change to change the retention to 5 minutes, code like following:

```
 "Resources" : {
      "Queue" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        "Properties" : {
          "QueueName" : "QueueA",
          "MessageRetentionPeriod": 300
        }
      }
    }
```

Which is pretty straightforward, I get this deployed (stack updated), and as expected, the retention was set to 5 minutes.

Then I want to reset it to default, so I deleted this line:

```
         "MessageRetentionPeriod": 300
```

I deployed it (stack updated again), but it didn't work, I waited for 1 hour as the doc says it can take up to 15 minutes to take effect, but it didn't.

My guess is if I don't declare the value of a property of SQS explicitly, CloudFormation can see that change, but the API it calls behind the scenes won't take effect, is it right?

Comment: You were updating a Queue rather than creating a new Queue? In that case, it probably simply didn't change that value. It would use the default if you were using the template to create a new queue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I created it, then all the operation were updating.  Sorry for confusing you, I will update the description.

Comment: Are you sure you had updated the stack from **Update Stack** button on the AWS CloudFormation console? Because the change in resource properties is read by CloudFormation so it must update the MessageRetentionPeriod to default also.

Comment: @AakashVerma I updated with aws CLI, should be the same as you do via console. And yes, it didn't take effect.

Comment: @kevinjom I know how stupid that sounds...but sometimes it does work through the other way :D But on an earnest note, I searched around and nothing was found.

Answer (score 1):

*MessageRetentionPeriod* is not a [required parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html) so you are not being forced to set it:

> *MessageRetentionPeriod*
>
> > The number of seconds that Amazon SQS retains a message. You can specify an integer value from 60 seconds (1 minute) to 1209600 seconds (14 days). The default value is 345600 seconds (4 days).
> >
> > Required: No
> >
> > Type: Integer
> >
> > Update requires: No interruption

However, when CF stack is updated you are removing the explicit setting of that value, not *reseting* it to the default. This is an expected behaviour.